# Tomcat Server Server run successfully, but it does not show me the local host 8080 page

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, server

Good afternoon,

When I run Tomcat Server in Spring Tool Suite, it tells me that it has been run successfully, but it does not show me the local host 8080 page.

So the server works for me, but it doesn't throw out the local host page.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you configured port 8080
2. Make sure you are visiting 'http://localhost:8080'
3. Check whether the ContextPath is configured
4. If it's still wrong, show me your service log

Answer (score 0):

Check port 8080; there might be another application using it. Close it first.